# birds of a feather flock together and guit by association

Tags: logic, ethics, fallacies

There is a saying "birds of a feather flock together" which usually boils down to People of similar character, background, or taste tend to congregate or associate with one another. Yet guilt by association is frowned upon by most people.

I believe there is some amounts of truth in both sentences, Isn't that somewhat of a contradiction ?

Comment: *"Yet guilt by association is frowned upon by most people."* -> Probably only when it is applied to them.  When they apply it to other people, it's fine.  I think if you did a serious survey about this, you'd be lucky to find a definitive "most people agree" attitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentences are:

(1) People of a similar character associate with one another.

(2) Guilt by association is frowned upon by most people.

Now I don't know what you mean by "somewhat of a contradiction", but saying that two statements are contradictory is a strong assertion. It is saying that those two statements imply a statement of the form "P and not-P". These statements are not in contradiction. An easy way to notice this is that both statements are empirical truths, and there is no way that two empirical truths can generate a contradiction.

Having said that, instead of (2) you might have been thinking of:

(2'): Guilt by association is morally wrong.

Note that (2') differs greatly by (2) since (2') is a normative claim and (2) is an empirical claim. Now, you might think that (1) and (2') are somewhat in tension: if someone in your group is guilty, and you have roughly similar character to them, doesn't some guilt transfer to you? This strikes me as fundamentally unfair since you didn't do anything. You can only be found morally responsible for what you in fact did.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I just wanted to something to think about, i was not aiming for correctness or thoroughness of question. I cant unfortunately upvote.

Comment: No problem, but in the future you should aim for correctness and thoroughness! These are virtues after all haha.